# Facebook sdk not posting picture from ios application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using the following code to post photo on facebook.

```
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos])
{


    FBShareDialogPhotoParams *params = [[FBShareDialogPhotoParams alloc] init];

    // Note that params.photos can be an array of images.  In this example
    // we only use a single image, wrapped in an array.
    params.photos = @[imageDetails.chosenImage];
    params.place=@"Abracadabra Snap! ios application";
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                                     clientState:nil
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                                   NSDictionary *results,
                                                   NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                                                       error.description);
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"Success!");
                                             }
                                         }];
}
```

It shows me a dialog where I write some text and click on post, and after I click post, it uploads the image and comes back to the calling controllers, but does not return either error or success and doesn't post the image on facebook either. Please help about this problem

Comment: Have you managed to login to Facebook?

Comment: you cant directly add image to post with this facebook sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY   THIS    ...in  Share Button......

```
- (IBAction)facebookPost:(id)sender 
{    
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {

        SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"ABC"];

        [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];

        [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]];

        [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) 
        {

            switch (result)
            {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                {
                    NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
                    break;
                }

                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                { 
                    NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];

        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a gem!

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, this requires the application to have a default facebook account configured on the device, or it will just fail. A better solution would be one that asks for posting permission for the app and post using a POST method. Or another one would be one that uses the installed facebook app to post. All are documented on the facebook developer page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your appdelegate, this ensures that the facebook app can send data back to your app. (taken from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                                      NSLog(@"Unhandled deep link: %@", url);
                                      // Here goes the code to handle the links
                                      // Use the links to show a relevant view of your app to the user
                                  }];

    return urlWasHandled;
}
```